# How to list all user groups in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, list, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to list users and at the same time with the groups added to each one of them.

How can I do this?

Below is an example I'm trying to do.

Thank you.

Serializer

```
class serializerUser(serializers.Serializer): 
     id           = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True) 
     first_name   = serializers.CharField() 
     last_name    = serializers.CharField() 
     groups       = serializers.CharField() 
     password     = serializers.CharField(write_only=True) 
     username     = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
```

views

```
class UserList(ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    serializer_class = serializerUser
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    def get_queryset(self):
        users = User.objects.select_related('group').all()
        return users
```

Error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in
> select_related: 'gsroup'. Choices are: (none)

Comment: select_related('groups')

Comment: at the. already tried. =(

Comment: With users = User.objects.prefetch_related ('groups'). All () Did not generate any errors. But nothing returns. Note: in the database users are related to groups. the result -> groups: "auth.Group.None"

Comment: op, its a ManyToMany field, prefetch_related is right.:)

Comment: But it did not work. the result is this: groups: "auth.Group.None"

Comment: for group in user.groups.all():print(g)  could show them

Comment: Does not work @Blackdoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got them in `user.groups`. If you want to show them along with the user, add the `groups` field to the Meta class fields list, for example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "groups",
        )
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your attention in serializer.py includes the groups field.

Comment: class serializerUser(serializers.Serializer):

    id                        = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    first_name          = serializers.CharField()
    last_name          = serializers.CharField()
    groups                = serializers.CharField()
    password            = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    username           = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

Comment: I using serializers.Serializer